# After 2 seconds run SIGALRM alarm command in C

Tags: c, linux, delay, alarm, execution-time

I write a C program and my code copies a file from a directory to another. If the process takes more than 2 seconds, every second it has to print "Process is continue". How to delay alarm command 2 seconds?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you tried?  Have you looked at the [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) system call?  What's the problem?  Yes, there are more modern alternatives (I'm sure), but for your task, it seems likely to be adequate.  You should show what you've tried so we can gauge what's an appropriate response.  (Grammatically, it should probably be "Process is continuing".)  Also, you're discussing functions or system calls in C, rather than commands.

Comment: I researched alarm() system call but i did not manage how to delay it. I am sorry for grammatical mistake. I think I should know execution time at any moment of termination.

Comment: `unsigned time_left = alarm(0);` cancels the current alarm, letting you know how much time was left (0 if there was no alarm set).  The BSD man page for `alarm(3)` notes "This interface is made obsolete by setitimer(2)" — a new(er) POSIX function (see [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html)).

Comment: So time_left let me know how much time passed ? It is an unsigned variable i cant control it with greater than 2 or etc. I looked settimer() it takes struct but i don't have struct in my code.

`unsigned time_left = alarm(0);
            if(time_left > 2) {
  signal(SIGALRM, set_alarm);
  alarm(1);
`}

I tried this it is non-sense I know but I am confused.

Comment: I ran signal it is working, but it prints immediately. It must start after 2 seconds from execution. How can I manage it ?

Comment: I solved it, i changed alarm(1); with alarm(2); and its done. How didn't i see it.

Comment: Well done!  Welcome to Software Development.  Sometimes, the solutions are very simple but it takes you ages to spot what you're doing wrong.  It's a fact of life — one you have to struggle to get over.

Comment: Thank you for your help.